# Piwik - How to pull Insights of click event/page views traffic day by day

Tags: matomo

Just wanted to ask if it's possible in Piwik http api to pull a click event or page views data counts that also contains a date from day by day just like on facebook Graph Insight.

I was using a Module Insights but it didn't gave a date.

Anyone can help? Thanks